# Trap handling and implicit subshells in shell scripts

Tags: shell, trap

Let's say you have a shell script that runs some sort of cleanup code
via an `EXIT` trap, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mytrap () {
  echo "It's a trap!" >&2
}

trap mytrap exit

echo I am at the end of the script.
```

This will, as expected, print out `It's a trap!` when the script
exits:

```
$ sh myscript
I am at the end of the script.
It's a trap!
```

You modify the script to add a function that generates some
output that ultimately gets piped to another command, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mytrap () {
  echo "It's a trap!" >&2
}

myfunc () {
  echo "I've got a bad feeling about this..."
}

trap mytrap exit

myfunc | cat > /dev/null

echo I am at the end of the script.
```

Because of the pipe, the code in `myfunc` is run in a subshell...and
subshells don't appear to inherit the `trap` behavior of the parent,
which means if you perform any actions here that should be cleaned up
by your trap code that won't happen.

So you try this:

```
myfunc () {
  trap mytrap EXIT
  echo "I've got a bad feeling about this..."
}
```

And it still fails to trigger `mytrap` when the subshell exits.  It
turns out that you need an explicit `exit`, like this:

```
myfunc () {
  trap mytrap EXIT
  echo "I've got a bad feeling about this..."
  exit
}
```

With the above code, `mytrap` will trigger appropriately upon exit
from the subshell:

```
$ sh myscript 
It's a trap!
I am at the end of the script.
It's a trap!
```

Is that expected behavior?  I was surprised by several things here:

- `trap` settings weren't inherited by subshells
- implicit exit from a subshell does not appear to trigger an `EXIT`
  trap

Comment: Implicit exit from a subshell triggers `EXIT` trap in some other shells such as `dash` and `lksh`. It triggers `EXIT` trap even in `bash`, if you have set `set -e` and some command in the subshell exits with non-zero status (like e.g. `false`). I wonder, if the behavior is somehow ruled by POSIX?

Comment: See also [my related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/647495/111181)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bash `trap` builtin allows the keyword `RETURN`.  Hence change:

```
trap mytrap EXIT
```

to:

```
trap mytrap RETURN
```

See the discussion of `trap` in [shell-builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands)